# Is Cassandra Update IF statement where the condition is an inequality expression supported?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh, cqlinq

Is `UPDATE IF [condition]` where [condition] is an inequality, supported by Cassandra CQL?

I had a look over the language reference and it seems that CQL should not be able to support the inequality through its grammar. I used the language reference from here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#updateStmt

What is confusing is that using the C# driver or CQLSH the query is executed successfully, but when doing the same thing from Datasax DevCenter I get an error.

I'm using a query similar to the one below:

```
UPDATE product
SET edit_date = [new_value]
WHERE customer_id = '4' AND code = 'AMZ-ISMDB' 
IF edit_date < [new_value]
```

The results are as follows:

- Datasax DevCenter throws an error when trying to execute the script snippet. The error I get is complaining about the inequality in the UPDATE IF part of the script.

  **There is one syntax error in the current script (see details below).
  Please fix it and try again.
    Line 29: no viable alternative at input '<'**
- If I use CLINQ with the Datasax C# driver the query is generated as above and when executed the update is persisted if the new edit_date is after the existing edit_date which is the expected behaviour.
- Using CQLSH the query runs successfully and the update is persisted

Comment: What is your cassandra and CQL version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that DevCenter has not been updated to support the latest syntax.

Inequality conditions were added in:
[CASSANDRA-6839](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6839)

Looks like they missed updating the docs when that was added.  I open [CASSANDRA-10752](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10752) to get that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in DevCenter version 1.6.0.